# How do I show a function is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I show that the subset

W= {f:$\mathbb R$→$\mathbb R$ ∣ f()= a + $b{x}^{2}$ where a,bϵ$\mathbb R,$}

is closed under pointwise addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: I presume the word 'closed' is missing, and the addition and multiplication are pointwise? Take two $f$,$g$ of this form and show that the sum $f + g$ is also of this form. Same for $cf$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$ a constant.

Comment: Yes pointwise addition and multiplication. So if I say take any f,g in W, (f + g)(x)= f(x) + g(x)= 2a + 2b$x^2$ which is in W does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that ought to do it

Comment: and for scalar multiplication take any cϵR and any fϵW, then f(cx))= c(f(x)) and repeat the same process as above?

Comment: Not quite. $f(ax) \neq af(x)$ in general. It's really the assertion that $f \in W \implies cf \in W$

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome - if you're happy please upvote my answer. Welcome to StackExchange Mathematics, Jacopo.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved in comments - the key point being to take two $f,g \in W$ and show that the sum $f+g \in W$, and so too $cf \in W$ for any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.